# Apache: mod_substitute rule to strip out all .html hyperlinks in a text

Tags: html, regex, apache, httpd.conf, substitution

```
Substitute "s|<a(.*)href=\"/(.*)\.html\"(.*)>|<a$1href=\"/$2\"$3>|i"
```

This is the substitute rule I'm using but looks like if in a paragraph I have more than one hrefs, only the trailing one is stripped out the html extension. Previous hrefs have no impact.

[image: k]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(.*)` means as many chars from this line as possible, so after matching the first `<a`, it will search for the farest `href` following. If you add a ? after the *, it will look for the smallest string matching `(.*?)` that still allows the rest to match.

```
Substitute "s|<a(.*?)href=\"/(.*?)\.html\"(.*?)>|<a$1 href=\"/$2\"$3>|i"
```